# Retrofit Returning Null Response Body

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to make a call to the FlickR API and am having difficulty as the response.body() is returning null.

I am not sure if it relates to my JSON/POJO mapping, but I cannot figure out how to access the response from Retrofit when I make the call to FlickR. I know that my call is being completed successfully as I am actually able to view the JSON through the logging interceptor.

**Model:**

```
public class Model {

Photos photos;
int code;
String stat;
String message; // when you text = null

public class Photos {

    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    private int page;
    @SerializedName("pages")
    @Expose
    private int pages;
    @SerializedName("perpage")
    @Expose
    private int perpage;
    @SerializedName("total")
    @Expose
    private String total;
    @SerializedName("photo")
    @Expose
    private List<Photo> photo = new ArrayList<Photo>();

    /**
     * @return The page
     */
    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    /**
     * @param page The page
     */
    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    /**
     * @return The pages
     */
    public int getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    /**
     * @param pages The pages
     */
    public void setPages(int pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    /**
     * @return The perpage
     */
    public int getPerpage() {
        return perpage;
    }

    /**
     * @param perpage The perpage
     */
    public void setPerpage(int perpage) {
        this.perpage = perpage;
    }

    /**
     * @return The total
     */
    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    /**
     * @param total The total
     */
    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    /**
     * @return The photo
     */
    public List<Photo> getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    /**
     * @param photo The photo
     */
    public void setPhoto(List<Photo> photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

}

public class Photo {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("owner")
    @Expose
    private String owner;
    @SerializedName("secret")
    @Expose
    private String secret;
    @SerializedName("server")
    @Expose
    private String server;
    @SerializedName("farm")
    @Expose
    private int farm;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("ispublic")
    @Expose
    private int ispublic;
    @SerializedName("isfriend")
    @Expose
    private int isfriend;
    @SerializedName("isfamily")
    @Expose
    private int isfamily;
    @SerializedName("url_m")
    @Expose
    private String urlM;
    @SerializedName("height_m")
    @Expose
    private String heightM;
    @SerializedName("width_m")
    @Expose
    private String widthM;

    public Photo(){

    }

    /**
     * @return The id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id The id
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return The owner
     */
    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    /**
     * @param owner The owner
     */
    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    /**
     * @return The secret
     */
    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

    /**
     * @param secret The secret
     */
    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    /**
     * @return The server
     */
    public String getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    /**
     * @param server The server
     */
    public void setServer(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    /**
     * @return The farm
     */
    public int getFarm() {
        return farm;
    }

    /**
     * @param farm The farm
     */
    public void setFarm(int farm) {
        this.farm = farm;
    }

    /**
     * @return The title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     * @param title The title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     * @return The ispublic
     */
    public int getIspublic() {
        return ispublic;
    }

    /**
     * @param ispublic The ispublic
     */
    public void setIspublic(int ispublic) {
        this.ispublic = ispublic;
    }

    /**
     * @return The isfriend
     */
    public int getIsfriend() {
        return isfriend;
    }

    /**
     * @param isfriend The isfriend
     */
    public void setIsfriend(int isfriend) {
        this.isfriend = isfriend;
    }

    /**
     * @return The isfamily
     */
    public int getIsfamily() {
        return isfamily;
    }

    /**
     * @param isfamily The isfamily
     */
    public void setIsfamily(int isfamily) {
        this.isfamily = isfamily;
    }

    /**
     * @return The urlM
     */
    public String getUrlM() {
        return urlM;
    }

    /**
     * @param urlM The url_m
     */
    public void setUrlM(String urlM) {
        this.urlM = urlM;
    }

    /**
     * @return The heightM
     */
    public String getHeightM() {
        return heightM;
    }

    /**
     * @param heightM The height_m
     */
    public void setHeightM(String heightM) {
        this.heightM = heightM;
    }

    /**
     * @return The widthM
     */
    public String getWidthM() {
        return widthM;
    }

    /**
     * @param widthM The width_m
     */
    public void setWidthM(String widthM) {
        this.widthM = widthM;
    }

    }

}
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
  photos: {
  page: 1,
  pages: 3683,
  perpage: 100,
  total: "368270",
  photo: [
       {
       id: "29264707352",
       owner: "84316756@N02",
       secret: "9ed355a86e",
       server: "8603",
       farm: 9,
       title: "Tercer Patio de los Claustros de la Compañía/ Arequipa",
       ispublic: 1,
       isfriend: 0,
       isfamily: 0,
       url_m:          "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8603/29264707352_9ed355a86e.jpg",
       height_m: "500",
       width_m: "333"
          },
        {
        id: "29339070436",
        owner: "146617764@N02",
        secret: "b52f1e9914",
        server: "8509",
        farm: 9,
        title: "2016-04-17 09.24.07",
        ispublic: 1,
        isfriend: 0,
        isfamily: 0,
        url_m: "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8509/29339070436_b52f1e9914.jpg",
        height_m: "281",
        width_m: "500"
       },
```

**LOGCAT**

```
09-03 15:11:33.037 1846-1846/com.troychuinard.flickr_test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.troychuinard.flickr_test, PID: 1846
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                                at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:118)
                                                                                at com.troychuinard.flickr_test.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:72)
                                                                                at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
09-03 15:14:21.858 1846-1846/com.troychuinard.flickr_test I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1846 SIG: 9
```

**Line 72**

```
         Log.v("RESPONSE_BODY", response.body().getTotal());
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchTerm;
private Button mRequestButton;
private Button mSearchButton;
private String mQuery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSearchTerm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ediText_search_term);
    mRequestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.request_button);
    mSearchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button_flickr);
    mRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mQuery = mSearchTerm.getText().toString();
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


            ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<Photos> call = apiInterface.getImages(mQuery);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Photos>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Photos> call, Response<Photos> response) {
                    Log.v("RESPONSE_CALLED", "ON_RESPONSE_CALLED");
                    String didItWork = String.valueOf(response.isSuccessful());
                    Log.v("SUCCESS?", didItWork);
                    Log.v("RESPONSE_CODE", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    Photos photos = response.body();
                    Log.v("RESPONSE_BODY", "response:" + photos);
                    String total = response.body().getTotal();
                    Log.v("Total", total);
                    List<Photos.Photo> photoResults = response.body().getPhoto();
                    for (Photos.Photo photo : photoResults) {
                        Log.v("PHOTO_URL:", photo.getTitle()
                        );
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Photos> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

    mSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent toSearch = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FlickRActivity.class);
            startActivity(toSearch);
        }
    });


}

//Synchronous vs. Asynchronous
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=1c448390199c03a6f2d436c40defd90e&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m")
    Call<Photos> getImages(@Query("text") String query);

}
```

}

Comment: Have you try checking if the response.errorBody() was not empty first? If there was an error in the request, the response.body() will be null.... Also, if you could post the retrofit call you are making, it would help.

Comment: I have posted the Main Activity which contains all Retrofit request information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310585/cannot-parse-json-response-object/39314214#39314214) your model is not correct your `stat: "ok"` at the end of Response is your mistake.

While you create a `Photos` Object you need a parent Model to keep both attribute (`photos` & `stat`)

So your model would be:

```
public class Model {

    Photos photos;
    int code;
    String stat;
    String message; // when you text = null


    public class Photos{
        int page;
        int pages;
        int perpage;
        int total;
        List<Photo> photo;



        public class Photo{
            String id;
            String owner;
            String secret;
            //rest of things

        }
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to change your `Call<Photos>` to `Call<Model>`.

Comment: Thanks I am trying to understand. I don't see how this model is different than my original code, and I don't understand what stat and message are  for. Not saying you are wrong just trying to figure out where it comes into play

Comment: @tccpg288 I test your query with simple text; if you scroll to end of response a **stat** attribute exist; Also if you send *null* value to server it's return **message** and **code**.

Comment: You get Null value because retrofit expect to see Object which contains **photos** and **stat** But saw **photos** and can't cast this object to each other :)

Comment: How do I scroll to the end of the response? I am having trouble even viewing the response...

Comment: I have updated my code. Can you write the exact line of code that would explain how to call getTotal(), which is in my "Photo" model, from the response.body()?

Comment: Add public getPhoto() in your Model class  which return your photo object; just like other getter in your photos class

Comment: copy following url in your browser to see response:

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=1c448390199c03a6f2d436c40defd90e&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m

Comment: Where did you get that URL from? I use the logging interceptor with Retrofit and received the following link: https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=1c448390199c03a6f2d436c40defd90e&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m&text=Tree